# How can I keep WCF from timing out?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a very simple WCF service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEngine
{
    #region Test code
    // test - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();
     }
```

implemented as follows:

```
public partial class Engine : IEngine
{
    private static int nTestCount = 0;
    string IEngine.Test()
    {
        try
        {
            nTestCount++;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return "Service OK " + nTestCount.ToString();
    }
     }
```

When I call the test service method 10 times, in about 10 seconds... I get this error:

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

( I tried to put in my web.config file but it doesn't show up here )
( help on posting the contents would be appreciated )

Update 1:

Here is the client code that invokes the service:

```
    private void btn_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.EngineClient eng = new EngineClient();
        textBox1.Text = eng.Test();
    }
```

Comment: Does it work fine if you call it once or do you get that error then too? Also, two things 1) Why is `nTestCount++` in a try/catch? 2) the `++` operator is not thread safe, it is not ok to do it on static variables. You must use `Interlocked.Increment(ref nTestCount);` instead or have some kind of locking enabled. Please update your question with the calling code, the problem is likely on that side of the code in how you are making your 10 calls.

Comment: Are you using the same connection every call or creating a new one?  If you're creating a new one are you closing your previous connection?

Comment: Scott - It works great the first 9 times I press but button invoking the client side code... but the 10th one fails (in a about as many seconds)  The test code is simply there to help me figure out how many times it takes for this service to "stop working"... once I figure it out... the integer will be removed along with the try catch.  :-)

Comment: Mumbo - I am creating a new connection every time... see updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing your connections when you are done with them, this is causing the server to tie up a connection until the garbage collector collects your object. The default max open sessions a server can handle is 10 for .net 3.5 and older ([it was raised to 100 * ProcessorCount in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx)).

Dispose of the engine and it should work fine.

```
private void btn_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(ServiceReference1.EngineClient eng = new EngineClient())
    {
        textBox1.Text = eng.Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your client connections after each use which after a certain period causes the service to run out of available connections.  Once the service reaches its max open connections, new connections will timeout waiting for a connect to clear up.

You need to close your connections when you're done with them by calling their Dispose() or wrapping them in using blocks

```
private void btn_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ServiceReference1.EngineClient eng = new EngineClient())
    {
        textBox1.Text = eng.Test();
    }
}
```